# IAD error on itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an error on itunes connect, it works perfectly until I click on the iAd section , I the get an error message saying :
 "itunes connect HTTP Status 500 - Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
type Exception report

message Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2934)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2310)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:909)
    com.apple.iad.security.filter.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:220)
    com.apple.iad.security.filter.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:125)
    com.apple.iad.portal.selfservice.server.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:87)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.57"

when it happened yesterday I thought the server was down but I can't find any info about it so it's probably on my side, any idea as to why or how I could solve this issue? thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here: The iAd network is down: https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/#app_homepage

> **iAd Network is temporarily unavailable.**
>   Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later. If the problem persist please contact us.

Comment: Really weird, it works with the link you just posted but not when I try to go the regular way ...

Comment: The iAd network is notorious for weird server problems.  So how about an upvote? :p